# What am I doing wrong with this multiple linear regression

Tags: python, excel, linear-regression, analysis

I am trying to improve my grasp of linear regression/multiple linear regression. I saw this video on YouTube where he used a regression tool in excel to perform linear regression on a set of data.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgfHefwK7VQ&list=PLo8L7S3J29iOX0pvRqAgLDDdwobNWqG9C&index=21&t=0s

His final answer using a prediction for A, B, and C as dependent variables was 45149.21

Cost was the independent variable

This is the method I've been using to try and replicate his results

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# create linear regression object
lm = LinearRegression()

# develop a model using these variables as predictor variables
X = df[['A Made', 'B Made', 'C Made']]   
Y = df['Cost']

# Fit the linear model using the three above-mentioned variables.
lm.fit(X , Y)

# value of the intercept
intercept = lm.intercept_

# values of the coefficients
coef = lm.coef_.tolist()

# final estimated linear model
Z = intercept + (coef[0] * 1200) + (coef[1] * 800) + (coef[2] * 1000)
```

The predicted value spit out is

```
Z = 10606.098714826765
intercept = 35108.59711204488
coefficient (list) = [2.072061216849437, 4.153422708041111, 4.796887088174573]
```

The actual data in question

```
data = {

    'Month':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19],
    'Cost':[44439,43936,44464,41533,46343,44922,43203,43000,40967,48582,45003,44303,42070,44353,45968,47781,43202,44074,44610],
    'A Made':[515,929,800,979,1165,651,847,942,630,1113,1086,843,500,813,1190,1200,731,1089,786],
    'B Made':[541,692,710,685,1147,939,755,908,738,1175,1075,640,752,989,823,1108,590,607,513],
    'C Made':[928,711,824,758,635,901,580,589,682,1050,984,828,708,804,904,1120,1065,1132,839]

}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I expected the predicted value to be close to that 44000 value. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: relieved to find the process was correct. Upon examining it again, the intercept printed out a -2 value. Then I made some adjustments where I assigned an intercept value and it is back to where it should be.

THANK YOU to all who answered. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just read your edit, make sure to keep learning and get in touch if there's anything I can help you with! (Mostly regarding regression problems)

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your code and got this when priting Z: `45714.69582687167` the only thing I changed is the import: `from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression()` to `from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression`

Answer (score 1):

Do it again, your process is correct. You do not need to manually extract coefficients and intercept.

```
x_test = [[1200, 800, 1000]]
y_predict = lm.predict(x_test)
```

output

```
array([[45714.69582687]])
```

Btw, fix `from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression`

Answer (score 1):

```py
Z = 45714.69582687167
```

That's what I get by running your code, which is close to 44000

And changed the import to

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```